# VB Script to convert excel to text exits with error code 9009

Tags: vb.net, excel, vbscript, vba

I have a VB Script in which i convert Excel ( .xls ) file to text file.
It exits with error code 9009.

I am running this script on a server on which Excel 2003 is installed, but not entire MS Office.

Below is the script

```
'Script Details:
'The script converts an excel file into a tab-delimited file
'The script requires two parameters - the source file name and target file name
'Author Maulik

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Script checks and exectues only if there are 2 parameters
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please Specify the Source File. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file>"
    Wscript.Quit 4
End If


txt_format = 20

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_path = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)

'WScript.Echo src_path

src_file = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)

'WScript.Echo src_file

full_file_path = src_path & "\" & src_file

'WScript.Echo full_file_path


Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook
Dim xlSheet
Dim strOutputFileName

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.EnableEvents = False

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(full_file_path)

For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets

With xlSheet
strOutputFileName = full_file_path & "." & xlSheet.Name & ".dat"    
xlSheet.SaveAs strOutputFileName, txt_format
End With

Next

xlBook.Close False

xlApp.Quit
```

Comment: have you tried running your code in MS Excel (VB Editor) to see if it's an error in your Excel code (tho it looks fine)

Comment: The SaveAs method of the Excel workbook object has as it's second argument an *XlFileFormat Enumeration* for CSV files, this is *xCSV* which outside Excel, in VBScript would be _6_

Comment: does your path have spaces in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that error I think is **Bad File Name or Number** because you have spaces in your path.

try this code below:

```
'Script Details:
'The script converts an excel file into a tab-delimited file
'The script requires two parameters - the source file name and target file name
'Author Maulik

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Script checks and exectues only if there are 2 parameters
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please Specify the Source File. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file>"
    Wscript.Quit 4
End If


txt_format = 6 ' xlCSV is 6, 20 is xlTextWindows !

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_path = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)

'WScript.Echo src_path

src_file = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)

'WScript.Echo src_file

full_file_path = src_path & "\" & src_file

'WScript.Echo full_file_path


Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook
Dim xlSheet
Dim strOutputFileName

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible =true ' false
xlApp.EnableEvents = False

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(full_file_path)

For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets

With xlSheet
strOutputFileName = """" & full_file_path & "." & xlSheet.Name & ".dat" & """"   
xlSheet.SaveAs strOutputFileName, txt_format
End With

Next

xlBook.Close False

xlApp.Quit
```

I hope that helps

Philip

Comment: Hi Everyone,
Thanks for your reply.

For development purpose, I am successfully able to run this code on my local  which has MS Office 2010 installed. 

But for use on server, this code is not working. The server has got only Excel 2003 installed and not entire MS Office 2003

Comment: I am using text_format = 20 because i want to convert the .xls file into a tab delimited text file

9009 error, from what i understand, means that it is not able to initialize the Excel.Application

Do i need to provide full path of Excel.exe where it is installed on the server ?

Comment: I think the space isnt an issue here. Because i am running this code on my local machine successfully. 

There is somethiing wrong with the way i am initializing it or the way i am using Excel.Application

Comment: are you sure it isn't because of spaces in the file path - normally a BAD FILE NAME OR NUMBER occurrs when a path isn't right ... it isn't a problem with Excel if Excel is installed then it'll be fine. Try the answer I gave

Comment: try running just these lines of code on the server *Dim xlApp
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible =true* and see if Excel is launched on the server. Then you will know it isn't an _Excel Automation_ issue

Comment: Hi Philip,
Thanks a lot of helping my out on this.

But it was an error in the way i was calling my VB script from the jobs.

It is working nice and fine now.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: School boy error...doh !
Its friday evening effect on my brains :)